# Math + formulas for calculating the distances to place holes in a pipe to produce specific notes

Tags: acoustics

I'm interested in making a PVC pipe that I can produce specific tones on. What formulas can I use to figure out where to put the holes along the body of the pipe to produce the tone I'm looking for?

Comment: A web search would have found [this link](http://rwgiangiulio.com/math/pipelength.htm) very quickly.  Try searching for "formula pipe organ".

Comment: The octave is a double frequency or wave length. So the pipe length is twice or a half for the octave. There are 12 notes in the octave. Thus the ratio of the lengths of the pipe for two consequetive notes is a number, which multiplied by itself 12 times gives 2. In other words, a root of 12th power of 2. It is 1.059463. Start with a pipe of 188mm less its internal diameter and change its length until you get the frequency of the note A to be exactly 440Hz. All other notes follow the rule above. Hope this helps.